# Confirmation email got Invalid token

Tags: asp.net, email, confirm

I'm adding confirmation email feature to my ASP.NET WebAPI project. The server can send email fine, however, the confirmation link always return "Invalid token".

I checked some reasons as pointed out here 
http://tech.trailmax.info/2015/05/asp-net-identity-invalid-token-for-password-reset-or-email-confirmation/ 
but it seems that none of them is the root cause

Below is my code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        IdentityResult result;           
            result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return GetErrorResult(result);
            }
            try
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Player");

                //Generate email confirmation token                                        
                //var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("GSEP");
                var provider = new MachineKeyProtectionProvider();
                userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<GSEPUser>(provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
                var code = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                code = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);

                EmailHelper emailHelper = new EmailHelper();
                string callBackUrl = emailHelper.GetCallBackUrl(user, code);
                EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage();
                message.Body = callBackUrl;
                message.Destination = user.Email;
                message.Subject = "GSEP Account confirmation";
                emailHelper.sendMail(message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Ok(GSEPWebAPI.App_Start.Constants.ErrorException(e));
            }         
    }
```

And now is EmailHelper

```
public class EmailHelper
{
    public string GetCallBackUrl(GSEPUser user, string code)
    {

        var newRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new { userId = user.Id, code = code });

        newRouteValues.Add("httproute", true);            
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext, RouteTable.Routes);
        string callbackUrl = urlHelper.Action(
                    "ConfirmEmail",
                    "Account",
                    newRouteValues,
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme
                    );
        return callbackUrl;
    }

    public void sendMail(EmailMessage message)
    {
        #region formatter
        string text = string.Format("Please click on this link to {0}: {1}", message.Subject, message.Body);
        string html = "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + message.Body + "\">link</a><br/>";

        html += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(@"Or click on the copy the following link on the browser:" + message.Body);
        #endregion

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress("myemail@example.com");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
        msg.Subject = message.Subject;
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", Convert.ToInt32(587));
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@example.com", "mypassword!");
        smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

And 2 MachineKey class

```
public class MachineKeyProtectionProvider : IDataProtectionProvider
{
    public IDataProtector Create(params string[] purposes)
    {
        return new MachineKeyDataProtector(purposes);
    }
}

public class MachineKeyDataProtector : IDataProtector
{
    private readonly string[] _purposes;

    public MachineKeyDataProtector(string[] purposes)
    {
        _purposes = purposes;
    }

    public byte[] Protect(byte[] userData)
    {
        return MachineKey.Protect(userData, _purposes);
    }

    public byte[] Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
    {
        return MachineKey.Unprotect(protectedData, _purposes);
    }
}
```

I also added machineKey tag in Web.config as some instruction pointed out. 
And finally is my confirmation email API

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return Ok("Confirm error");
        }
        IdentityResult result;
        try
        {
            result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
        {
            // ConfirmEmailAsync throws when the userId is not found.
            return Ok("UserID not found");
        }

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok("Confirmation succesfully");
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok(result.Errors);
        }
    }
```

Please show me where am I go wrong

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. But I though of adding the answer as it could help others.

You are using the below code

```
string callbackUrl = urlHelper.Action(
                    "ConfirmEmail",
                    "Account",
                    newRouteValues,
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme
                    );
```

and the `UrlHelper.Action` **already does the url encoding for you in the latest MVC versions**. So here in your code you are doing the encoding twice (one inside the `Register` and another inside `GetCallBackUrl` using `urlHelper.Action`)  and that is why you are getting the invalid token error.